# Finding the radius of convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Find the radius of convergence of:

$$\sum \frac{(K/e)^{3K}}{3K!}(7x)^K.$$

I figured that the ratio test could be used because of the factorial. Can can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

$$a_k:=\frac{k^{3k}}{e^{3k}(3k)!}(7x)^k\Longrightarrow\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|=7|x|\frac{(k+1)^{3k+3}}{e^{3k+3}(3k+3)!}\frac{e^{3k}(3k)!}{k^{3k}}=$$

$$=\frac{(k+1)^3}{(3k+1)(3k+2)(3k)}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{3k}\frac{7}{e^3}|x|\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}\frac{1}{27}\cdot e^3\cdot\frac{7}{e^3}|x|=\ldots$$

Try to take it from here

Comment: Great Thanks! just a quick concept check, the last expression, does that equal 1?  and therefore R would equal 27/7 ?

Comment: You in fact want the last expression to be *less* than one, thus getting that $\,|x|<\frac{27}{7}\,$ ...